# ExtJS configure store to write list of models under a property name

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a model like this:

```
Ext.define('Policy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'sting',
            phantom: true,
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return record.get('a') + '@' +
                    record.get('b');
            }
        },
        {name: 'a', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'b', type: 'string'}]
});
```

Where the PK of each record is `a` and `b`. The store looks like this:

```
Ext.define('Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Policy', 
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        simpleSortMode: true,
        batchActions: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty: 'id'
        },
        writer: {
            nameProperty: 'mapping'
        },
        api: {
            create:'/batch',
            read: '/policies',
            update: '/batch',
            destroy: '/batch'
        }
    }
});
```

**How can I configure the store so that when it POSTS to /batch when calling `store.sync()`, the payload looks like this and only consists of dirty records**:

```
{
    "policies": [{
        "a": "AA",
        "b": "BB",
    }, {
        "a": "AAA",
        "b": "BBB"
    },...]
}
```

where there is a `policies` property and under it is an array of dirty policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create whatever structure you want by making a manual `Ext.Ajax()` call. You have to submit only the dirty records yourself.